# SiriShortcuts doesn't ask for Boolean parameters

Tags: swift, ios13, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I'm implementing `SiriKit` for my app, which is basically an alarm clock. I want the conversation to go something like this:

> Hey, Siri, open 1337AlarmClock
>
> -Would you like to set an alarm?
>
> Yes
>
> -What time?
>
> 3 A.M
>
> -Alarm has been set for 3 A.M

My first parameter is thus a `Boolean` which my second parameter, a `DateComponents`, depends upon. I've implemented the `intent handler` for this correctly, and has set the `success code` to `.continueInApp` since I need to start my app after success and handle the parameters. But Siri never asks for my parameters, just blindly opens the app with the parameters set to nil. I do see the parameters in the Shortcuts app and can specify them there, but I want to do it through Siri.

**If I, however, change the first parameter to a `String` instead of a `Boolean`, Siri starts to ask the questions and my app is opened once I've provided the parameters.** Is there something wrong with the `Boolean` type for `SiriIntents` or what am I doing wrong here? Below are images of my `Intents.intentdefinition`.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out a few minutes after I posted my question - as usual. The thing is that Siri will only ask for parameters if she *doesn't already have a parameter value*. If you look at the second image in my original post you can see that the section `Relationship` has value set to `true`. This means that `true` will be the `default value` thus Siri won't ask me for it. You'll also notice that you can't have a `Boolean` type set as any other than `true` or `false` and also **has** to be set.

In order to go around this problem I created my own `custom parameter type` and added a third option `Undecided` which I set as the `default value`. Siri now ask properly - and can handle a **Yes/No** answer.

Comment: Hi @ClockWise,
I working on the same and i am trying to create custom parameter but dont have idea how to make it. so can you please guide me how can i make custom type param.... i have posted the similar question here please look into it and help me 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61614972/create-custom-type-parameter-in-sirikit

Comment: I have to implement the same feature like boolean parameter type, so it would be good if you can share some code snippet here.