# Create custom type parameter in sirikit

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirikit

I am working on siri kit and try to create own datatype in Intents.intentdefinition.
i refer soupchef demo project which was presented by apple on last WWDC 2019 and in that demo project **toppings** fields has a **custom** type.
So how custom type is showing and come in datatype/dropdown list? see below
[image]

How can i create my custom type field?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

On the left in the screenshot there are `OrderSoup`, `Soup`, `OrderType`, `OrderDetails`. If you look in in the lower parts on the left, there is a search bar and on the left of that search bar there is a minus sign and a plus sign. Click the plus one and you can define your own custom type or custom enum. When defined they are then accessible in the dropdown menu in your screenshot.

Comment: Right but after creating our own enum(soup, ordertype) and Type(OrderDetail) it will show in dropdown list under the enum and type section and these enum and type is available for all parameter once it will create, In above demo custom type is available only for topping param and custom type is listed in default datatype list not under the enum and type section.... This is my question how custom type is listing in list and create.